# AngularJS - Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

(Full error message below)

Causing all of my script to fail, and can't even run a simple $scope message.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cj5pe43k/5/.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div id="test" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:#000;width:100vw;height:100vh;color:#fff;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;"><p>{{message}}</p></div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })
})

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Main Controller Active';
})
```

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   justpayrollApp        due to: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'justpayrollApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I'm not a JsFiddle guy so I put your code into a Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/rFDtZ65kKYpYhPvyuKP9?p=preview) and it works just fine.  I can't see where in your fiddle that your js gets imported ... but again I'm not familiar with the inner workings of JsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

First, put **angular.js** script above the others.

Then, put your app script into **the bottom of the body element** of your page.

Then, delete one of two **angular-resource.js** dependencies you have. Should be only one instance of a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As you seems to be using the Angular native routing system, you don't need to include `ngRoute`. Furthermore, that is not exactly how you should use it: for each route, you are specifying a controller, so you don't have to specify it in the body element.

There are several things that which had to be resolved in your code, so here I fixed your Fiddle here:

**<kbd>[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83o6y3pn/)</kbd>**

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure this wills solve the issues but one mistake that I can see is using same 
  `.when('/',`
in every route.
 In first case you can put `when('/index'` and in 2nd case `when('/home'`
something like that

Check out this [routing in angularjs](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)